# How to pass custom component in title in top bar in react native navigation (wix)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have created a chat app in react native. Now I want to create app header similar like whatsapp with DP and text on header. For this I need to pass custom component on top bar as in react native navigation (wix), in top bar title accepts only string. I have gone through various links but got no success.

Any help is appreciated.

Reference image given below.

[image: Whatsapp header image - with DP and text]

**Note**: I am using react native navigation (wix) version 4.8.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the header in react navigation and create a custom header component and pass as prop or children,
at least thats how I do it.

in component file, before exporting

```
ComponentName.navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
```

and then just pass header

```
<ComponentName header={jsx} />
```

Comment: I am using react native navigation. This solution not working in my case.